# Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'No static method checkBuilderRequirement

Tags: java, c#, xamarin.forms

After updating to Xamarin.Forms 4.8 i get this error when application starts:

```
Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'No static method checkBuilderRequirement(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;)V in class Ldagger/internal/Preconditions; or 
its super classes (declaration of 'dagger.internal.Preconditions' appears in /data/app/com.codex.MojLek-
ELK-GTa_ywWpF5Na88sJeQ==/base.apk)'
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Please add the code that produces the exception

Comment: @MDK when i start the application i get this exception

Comment: [link](https://prnt.sc/v2d2xq)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I installed the latest Xamarin.Google.Dagger NuGet package into my Xamarin.Android instance and that seems to have fixed it for me. Hope that works for you.

Comment: You can mark this answer later which will help more people with same problem:).

Comment: What is Dagger?  I installed the updates for Firebase and Google Play and that's what broke my setup.  This fix worked for me.

Comment: I tried the solution recommended here and I am still running into the exception. Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: @AnthonyIacono update all nuget packages, aslo Firebase. Clean/Rebuild Project must work

Comment: I don't know, why this package not included in the dependencies by default?

Comment: I had to restart visual studio because it gave me this error ".... Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider ...." but in the end it worked

Comment: The whole Google Play Services / Firebase packages dependencies for Xamarin are a mess right now. A few days ago I had to downgrade a specific transient dependency one minor version (!) because of some class that was missing. Great stuff. Thanks for this in any case, this worked for me!

Comment: @TonyLugg "Xamarin.Google.Dagger" is referenced in the transitive dependencies of Firebase and Google Play nugets. But I think that they referenced a too old version of "Xamarin.Google.Dagger", which does not consist of the classes the build is complaining about.

Comment: Updated the package Xamarin.Google.Dagger from 2.13.0 to 2.27.0 and the error disappeared.

Comment: It worked also in my case. It should be included in the official docs of Microsoft